# How many attempts do websocket-client's send() do?

Tags: python, websocket

I use the Python package [websocket-client](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/) to take care some client-server discussion.

Assume I do the following:

```
import websocket
MAX_TIMEOUT = 1 * 60  # Maximum time to wait to establish the connection to the server.
ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://128.52.195.211:8080/websocket")
ws.settimeout(MAX_TIMEOUT)
ws.send("Hello, World!")
```

How many attempts will `ws.send()` do to try to send the message to the server? Only 1?

Comment: yes, only 1, but you can implement a loop to retry on failure and put in place a max_retries.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [library source code](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client/blob/master/websocket/_core.py), it clearly shows that there's no retry implemented.

`ws.send` creates frames (chunks) from the payload, and then sends each frame 1 by one in `ws.send_frame`